# Spring boot oauth2 "/auth/oauth/token" forbidden

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm setting up a basic oauth2 Authorization server. Here's my  Application Config.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class Application {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/user" }, produces = "application/json")
    public Map<String, Object> user(OAuth2Authentication user) {
        Map<String, Object> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
        userInfo.put("user", user.getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal());
        userInfo.put("authorities", AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(user.getUserAuthentication().getAuthorities()));
        return userInfo;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


}
```

WebSecurityConfigurer

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;


    @Configuration
    public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
            return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
        }


        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                    .inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("john.carnell").password("password1").roles("USER")
                    .and()
                    .withUser("william.woodward").password("password2").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
        }
    }
```

and my Oauth2Config

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("eagleeye")
                .secret("thisissecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "password", "client_credentials")
                .scopes("webclient", "mobileclient");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve a token from localhost:8080/auth/oauth/token using postman but it only throws this error.

```
{
  "error": "unauthorized",
  "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

and here's the value I am passing from postman

[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe you are missing the authentication against the http calls? What happens if you add `@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }` to `WebSecurityConfigurer `? (Kind of hard to tell without logs, I thought `@EnableResourceServer` would have done this for you already)

Comment: Add the client_id and grant_type to the URL of the post request in postman. like : .../oauth/token?client_id=eagleeye&grant_type=password.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the endpoint but it returned an error but that's for another question. I just changed the url from `localhost:8080/auth/oauth/toke`n to `localhost:8080/oauth/token`

Comment: The other error you're talking about is getting an unauthorized when you want to access /user endpoint using the bearer token? If it's so, I'm facing the same problem. Did you found a solution?